# MySQL: specific sort by adding extra condition clause from another column parameter

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause

I  have issue sorting the result from query extracting data from two tables named `products` and `productsml`. Both are linked by the key field `ProductID`.

In `productsml` table records as stored in this order show below, I store different translation of the product name under `ProductName`, making it unique based on `LanguageID` column

```
|ProductID|LanguageID|ProductName|
| :---: | :---: | :---: |
| 1 | 1 | Тea |
| 1 | 2 | Чай |
| 1 | 3 | Çay |
| 2 | 1 | Coffe |
| 2 | 2 | Кафе |
| 2 | 3 | Kahve |
| 3 | 1 | Cup a-type |
| 3 | 2 | Чаша |
| 3 | 3 | Fincan |
```

What I need is get as result first all records with the given `LanguageID` = 1 condition, sorted `ProductName` ASC.

Please note: **I do not want to put under general WHERE section `LanguageID` = 1** as it will limit searching only only to the rows with this condition. I want to make a search over **the all `ProductName`** data for the matching without limitations, but result should be only unique ProductIDs avoid doubling - because of this I'm adding DISTINCT at the begining of my query. This is the reason to try to put it under OrderBy clause IF for the languagesorting the result under given language first:

Expected result is (I show below second and third column only for visualization of the question in reality I need just first one):

```
|ProductID|LanguageID|ProductName|
|:---:|:---:|:---:|
| 2| 1| Coffe|
| 3| 1| Cup a-type|
| 1| 1| Tea |
```

Trying this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `products`.`ProductID`
FROM
    `products`,
    `productsml`
WHERE
    `products`.`ProductID` = `productsml`.`ProductID` 
    AND `products`.`ProductIsActive` = 1 
    AND `products`.`ProductName` LIKE '%а%'
ORDER BY
    `productsml`.`LanguageID` = '1',
    `productsml`.`ProductName` ASC
```

It works fine also when I reverse to `productsml`.`ProductName` DESC.

My problem is when I set `LanguageID` to 2 or 3 (keeping rest of theinputs in query same as above) the result is unfortunatelly same as with condition `LanguageID` =1 ...

with `LanguageID` = 2 it should be:

```
|ProductID|LanguageID|ProductName|
|:---:|:---:|:---:|
| 2| 2| Кафе|
| 1| 2| Чай|
| 3| 2| Чаша|
```

with `LanguageID` = 3 it should be:

```
|ProductID|LanguageID|ProductName|
|:---:|:---:|:---:|
| 2| 3| Çay|
| 1| 3| Fincan|
| 3| 3| Kahve|
```

Please help to fix it.

Many thanks!

Comment: 'records as stored in this order'- data is not stored in any particular order

Comment: I am baffled by the statement 'Please note: I do not want to put under general WHERE section LanguageID = 1 as it will limit searching only only to the rows with this condition. I want to make a search over the all ProductName data for the matching without limitations',- are you seeking to avoid hard coding? also you should publish the failed code because what you say isn't obviously possible.

Comment: yes, exaclty, I tried to avoid hard coding. there is no error in query as result, it works, but not as expected. I found a way to fix it with moving hard condition for the language in another parent query using IN like this: SELECT
    `ProductID` FROM `productsml` WHERE `LanguageID` = 1 AND `ProductID` IN ( <as above query removing all ORDER BY>) ORDER BY `productsml`.`ProductName`  DESC

Comment: Please add your table definition in full including collation.

Comment: You select based on WHERE altering the order by clause will make no difference to that - you should check the collation of what is stored against that used in the where clause.